# ajax call going to error function rather than success whenever I pass email address in data,

Tags: ajax

Whenever I pass the email address in the ajax data then it will go to the error function. I have tried following:

```
var emailid = $("#email").val();
var dataString = {'email': emailid};

$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url:'subscribeaction.php',
   data: dataString,
   datatype: 'text',
   success: function(data) {
       alert("data");
   },
   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       alert(ajaxOptions);
   }
});
```

But this is not the solution. Anybody could help?

Comment: dataType should be 'json'

Comment: Thank you for the response. but i tried it also. but did not work .

Answer (score 0):

You can try to edit your ajax call:

```
dataType: 'json',
data: JSON.stringify(dataString),
contentType: 'application/json'
```

If error persists, kindly log the ajax error then show to us.

Edit: (getting ajax error)

```
error: function (response) {
      var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
      console.log("Message: " + r.Message);
      console.log("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
      console.log("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
}
```

Comment: i get that in the console log

Object { readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(), statusCode: statusCode(), abort: abort(), state: state(), always: always(), catch: catch(), 9 more… }

Comment: @plaxonic can you please specify the exact error message

Comment: actually i did not get anything else .. just the part after the Object..:(

Comment: @plaxonic add this to your code `console.log( JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));`

Comment: its showing syntax error

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: then try to remove `JSON.parse`.. just log straight the `xhr.responseText`

Comment: @plaxonic see my edit on how to properly get the ajax error

Comment: i appriciate your time but it also getting syntax error.. :(


SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data